# Access database too slow populating DatagridView

Tags: vb.net

I have an app with several datagridviews, and now, with more than 260 rows, my datagrid is too slow filling up, I don't know how I can lower the time.

Here is my codes:

```
Public cs As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\BD_Estaleiro.accdb"

Public con As New OleDbConnection(cs)

Public cmd As OleDbCommand

Public dr As OleDbDataReader

Public query As String
```

Reader Function:

```
    Public Function executar_query_Reader(ByVal Instrucao As String) As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim datareader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing 

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Instrucao, con) 
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
        con.Open()
        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader 

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'mensagem de erro, se aplicavel
    Finally

    End Try

    Return datareader 'retornar os dados atraves da variavel datareader
End Function
```

Populating the Datagrid:

```
Public Sub carregar_saidas(ByVal DG As DataGridView)

    n_rows = 0
    DG.Rows.Clear()
    query = "Select * from tbl_saidas as s, tbl_produtos as p Where s.Produto=p.Produto Order By s.Data DESC"
    dr = executar_query_Reader(query)
    While dr.Read
        n_rows += 1
        Dim n As Integer = DG.Rows.Add()
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = dr("ID")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = dr("s.Produto")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(2).Value = dr("s.Quantidade")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(3).Value = dr("Unidade")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(4).Value = dr("Obra")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(5).Value = Format(dr("Data"), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(6).Value = Format$(CSng(dr("Valor_uni")), "###,####,##0.00") & " €"
        DG.Rows.Item(n).Cells(7).Value = Format$(CSng(dr("Total")), "###,####,##0.00") & " €"
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are you manually creating rows and poking data to it?  A DGV can be very fast when used correctly: fill a datatable and set it as the DataSource for the control.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: you should be able to data-bind the grid directly to the query result instead of manual looping. Also, perhaps the query itself is slow. MS Access is not a great choice as the back-end to another application

Comment: You should stop and research the capabilities of the DB provider tools and how to properly use them.  There is nothing reusable about a DBCommand object - and you already create a `New` one when you use it - but it is declared as a global object.  The combo of a DataAdapter and DataTable make Db ops very simple - mostly you just end up handling validation...you dont even have to write the SQL

Answer (score 3):

Rather than adding individual Rows and Columns, you want to **bind** to the grid:

```
Public Sub carregar_saidas(ByVal DG As DataGridView)
    Dim query As String = "Select * from tbl_saidas as s, tbl_produtos as p Where s.Produto=p.Produto Order By s.Data DESC"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = executar_query_Reader(query)
    DG.DataSource = dr
End Sub
```

You'll need to have defined the columns on DataGridView to map the fields in the data reader.

You should also look into modifying the `executar_query_Reader()` method to support **parameterized queries**.